# Android Emulator: select AVD (Android Virtual Device) to run by default

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have added a second Virtual Device to test a different screen resolution (QVGA), but now I wanna switch back to the first AVD (HVGA) again. How can I set the virtual device in Eclipse to be used by default or even specifically for my project? In the properties I can only set the API level.

I also couldn't find any information in the [command line tool documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/avd.html) to set this manually.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

In Eclipse, click on Run in the toolbar then Run Configurations. Select your application and click on the Target tag. You can then select which AVD to use or set it to manual so it asks you each time you run the app.

Note that if the AVD's Android version is lower than the Minimum API level set in the Manifest, the AVD will not appear in the list.

Comment: This is correct but it is worth mentioning :
If the AVD's Android version is lower then the Minimum API level set in the Manifest, the AVD will not appear in the list.

Answer (score 4):

In AndroidManifest.xml, see that your minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion match your device.

Answer (score 0):

In new Eclipse Kepler version, right click your project, then click Run as->Run Configurations->"Target" tab, you will see all AVDs in the list, select one as a preferred one, then "Apply" and "Run"